# Google chrome cursor remains as 'loading' after jquery load()

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cursor

I have a simple jquery load call as follows (triggered on a link click)

```
$("#mydiv").load('/link/to/my/page.cfm', {
"page_id": page_id
});
```

In Chrome after the POST request is sent (with the results successfully received and loaded in #mydiv) the cursor remains as 'loading' (as well as the icon to the left of the window's tab).

I cannot seem to be able to overwrite this cursor even with css, and even if i refresh the page the cursor is still stuck like this until I close and reopen the tab.

Any idea what's causing this??? No other browsers have presented this problem

Thanks!!
Anna